# Switching Regulator Current Conversion

Tags: buck, switching

Can a switching regulator deliver more current than the input side can provide just at a lower voltage?

For example if I have a 10V 1A (10W) input source going through a switching regulator (100% efficient) can I have a 5V 2A (10W) output? Or will the switching regulator be limited to 5V at 1A and 50% duty cycle?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A switching regulator can indeed provide a higher current at a lower voltage (compared to its input).

The mechanism of a SMPS is a cycle where an inductor is first 'charged' with magnetic energy (from the input side), and then discharged into the output side. Each side needs a capacitor to smooth these current peaks. With a higher voltage less (average) current is needed to built up a certain amount of magnetic energy than with a lower voltage, hence at the lower voltage the (average) current will be higher.

With a standard down converter there is also the effect that during the charge part of the cycle (dark blue arrow) the current flows through the inductor, but *also into the output*. Hence the output current *must* be higher than the input current, because the discharge cycle adds to this current.

[image]

Comment: Much obliged. Wasn't sure if the energy in the inductor is dissipated before the next pump cycle.

Comment: It does not need to be fully discharged, but in the steady state all energy that is added in the charge part must be transferred to the output in the discharge part (otherwise it would not be steady).